# Como quitar esta linea de puntos que se forman entre las llaves ?? Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

No recuerdo cuando se agrego esto pero ya me molesta, intente desinstalando todas las extensiones que tengo pero no resulto.

[image: Imagen]

Comment: ¿¿Notación húngara?? ¡A la hoguera! 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo tengo el Visual Studio en inglés así que te digo la secuencia de acciones en ese idioma, si lo tienes en español busca los equivalentes.

Ve al menú *Tools - Options* y ahí selecciona *Text Editor - General* y desmarca *Show structure guide lines* bajo *Display*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es exactamente igual en español: Herramientas, opciones, editor de texto, general, Mostrar, "Mostrar líneas guía de estructura"